# Flutter test - FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30) - MacOS

Tags: flutter, macos, dart, path-provider

In running `flutter test` on MacOS I am getting this error:
`FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/mock' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)`

Note that it is working fine on Windows and Ubuntu.

I am using the `path_provider` package, following this example here:
https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/path_provider/path_provider/test/path_provider_test.dart

and overriding the values:

```
import "package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart";
import "package:path_provider_platform_interface/path_provider_platform_interface.dart"
    show PathProviderPlatform, StorageDirectory;
import "package:plugin_platform_interface/plugin_platform_interface.dart";


const String kTemporaryPath = "/mock/temporaryPath";

class MockPathProviderPlatform extends Mock
    with MockPlatformInterfaceMixin
    implements PathProviderPlatform {
  @override
  Future<String> getTemporaryPath() async {
    return kTemporaryPath;
  }
```

I tried to change permissions in the current directory with
`sudo chmod -R 777 <current-directory` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to remove the leading `/` in the `kTemporaryPath`

```
const String kTemporaryPath = "mock/temporaryPath";
```

Also, good idea to add the `mock` directory (or however you named it) directory in `.gitignore`